# MYSQL JSON_MERGE and Group By

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have the following table of data

[image]

What I am trying to do is `GROUP BY` timestamp and `JSON_MERGE` the objects. What I expect as a result is the following.

[image]

I expected the following query to work but I just get an error

```
SELECT timestamp, JSON_MERGE(json)
FROM data
GROUP BY timestamp, JSON_MERGE(json)
```

The error I am getting is

> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_MERGE'

Answer (score 1):

Assemble desired JSON using string functions and then cast it into JSON.

Example data

```
create table data (json json, timestamp datetime);

insert into data values
('{"a": 1}', '2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
('{"b": 2}', '2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
('{"c": 3}', '2016-10-01 11:11:11'),
('{}', '2016-10-01 11:11:11'),
('{"c": 33}', '2016-10-01 11:11:11');
```

Query to merge all `json` values grouped by timestamp

```
select cast(
  concat('{',  -- wrap everything in root object '{ ... }'
    group_concat(
      -- strip parenthesis from individual item representation
      -- '{"foo": 1}' -> '"foo": 1'
      substring(json, 2, length(json) - 2)),
  '}') as json) json,
timestamp
from data
-- skip empty JSON values to avoid getting extra comma during 
-- group_concat
where json != JSON_OBJECT()  
group by timestamp;
```

Query result

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| json             | timestamp           |
|------------------+---------------------|
| {"a": 1, "b": 2} | 2016-10-01 00:00:00 |
| {"c": 3}         | 2016-10-01 11:11:11 |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

Several caveats:

- Behaviour of this snippet is different from `JSON_MERGE()`, for example:

  - When two or more properties have the same name their values are
    overwritten instead of being merged into array of values
  - It can't merge objects with arrays
- Solution as presented only works with objects as a top level entity
  and not with arrays. It can be modified to work with arrays.
- If relies on string representation of JSON objects beginning and 
  ending with curly brackets `{}`. This might change in future versions 
  of the server.